# problem in allocating kernel memory by malloc() from user space?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is there any protection provided by kernel? Because when we tried to allocate memory using an
malloc() from user space, the kernel allowed to allocated around 124
MB of memory, and when we try to write into it, the kernel crashed. If there
was protection of kernel memory area, this wouldn't have happened

Comment: Show the complete code and describe environment. And it is "kernel" not "kernal".

Comment: @basu sagar: Did you intend to undo the spelling correction to your question title?

Comment: @sagar - Please post the code in question, if possible.

Comment: I voted to delete my own answer, as the edited question is now completely different from the original question, and thus my answer no longer makes any sense.

Comment: This question still doesn't make sense. kmalloc() is a kernel space API for kernel memory allocation so it wouldn't make sense for user-space. @sagar can you post the code in question to make it clear?

Answer (score 5):

In kernel-space there is no memory protection. Then again, malloc() isn't available in kernel-space, so what are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

[Allocating memory in the kernel](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6930) requires special consideration. It would be very helpful if you could post your code, or better explain your need for 'guaranteed' memory within kernel space.

Please keep in mind, *kernel space* is not `_infinite_`, in user space the *kernel* is what manages overcommitment. You have a very, very hard limit on memory *within the kernel* and lots of consumers competing to use it.

Again, if you post your code, many here could help you come up with a better design, which I believe is what you probably need.

Note, the link is from 2006. This illustrates my other point, what *version* of the kernel are you working with?